# Opencv Python ( Matching Shapes function in python)

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to know how to use cv2.matchShapes() function for a video feed from my camera . I want to get continuous values each time the frame changes .
How do I write a python script that does this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have not camera right now and can't test.
But If I can understand you correctly you can use generator for this purposes and do something like this:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
known_shapes = [ ... ] # list of your known shapes could be in format: [[shape_name, shape_vector_data], ...]

def live_comparator():
    while True:
        # get the current frame and initialize the occupied/unoccupied text
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # if the frame could not be received, then we have reached the end of the video
        if not ret:
            break

        # convert it to grayscale
        # and blur it if you need of-course
        frame= cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1)
        frame= cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (21, 21), 0)

        for known_shape_name, known_shape_vector in known_shapes:
            retval = cv2.MatchShapes(frame, known_shape_vector , method=CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, parameter=0)

            yield (known_shape_name, retval)

for known_shape_name, retval in live_comparator():
    # do what you want with matched data
```

My apologizing if I propose you not exact you want, I can't understand your question for 100%. If it is not you want just please ignore.

Comment: I want to compare sign language gestures to pre existing data . How do I go about creating the known_shapes array that you have mentioned in the begenning ?